# I don´t catch my javascript file with spring mvc

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have an app web developed with spring 2.5.6. But I have a problem with javascript file because my app don´t catch those files. I don´t work with them and for more I make, I don´t find a solution.

This is my structure

```
src
   java
      controller
   test
   resource
   static
      js
        files.js
   WEB_INF
      pages
      spring
      lib 
      web.xml
```

Those are my files
web.xml

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

  <display-name>Web Logistic</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-beans.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd  
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"> 

...

<!--     Configuramos Spring MVC -->
    <import resource="mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml"/>

</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">  

...

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" >
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value> org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value> 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- View Resolvers -->
<!--    Resuelve la ubicion de las vistas .jsp de @Controllers en la ruta /WEB-INF/pages -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    ...

</beans>
```

index.jsp (with call to javascript file)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>    
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/md5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function passwordToMD5()
                {
                    alert("estamos en el metodo de MD5");
                    var aleat = document.forms[0].aleat;
                    var jqPassClear = document.forms[0].password;
                    alert(aleat.value);
                    alert(jqPassClear.value);
                    //document.forms[0].user.value = $.trim(document.forms[0].user.value);

                    if(jqPassClear.value != "")
                    {
                        alert("entramos en el método jqPassClear");
                        alert($.trim(jqPassClear.value)));
                        document.forms[0].password.value = hex_md5(hex_md5($.trim(jqPassClear.value)));
                        //document.forms[0].password.value = hex_md5(aleat.value);
                        //document.forms[0].password.value = hex_md5(aleat.value);
                        alert(document.forms[0].password.value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.forms[0].password.value = "";
                    }

                    //document.forms[0].passwordClear.value = document.forms[0].user.value;
                }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form modelAttribute="login" action="" method="post">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="message.user.userName" text="default text" /></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" />
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><spring:message code="message.user.password" text="default text" /></td>
                <td><form:password path="password" />
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            ...
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" onclick="passwordToMD5();" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my filter

```
public class ProvisionResourceDispatcherServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7319714368828547681L;

    @Override
    public void init () throws ServletException
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String servletPath = req.getServletPath (); // /resource

        String url = servletPath;
        String lastPath = StringUtils.substringAfterLast (servletPath, "/");
        String extension = StringUtils.substringAfterLast (lastPath, ".");

        try
        {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty (extension)
                    && ("js".equals (extension) || "css".equals (extension) || "jpg".equals (extension))
                    || "bmp".equals (extension) || "gif".equals (extension))
            {
                dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher (url);
            }

            if (dispatcher != null)
            {
                dispatcher.include (req, rsp);
            }
            else
            {
                rsp.sendError (404);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            if (!rsp.isCommitted ())
            {
                rsp.sendError (500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using a 5 year old version of spring? It won't fix this issue but I would seriously look at upgrading. Springs changed a heck of a lot in that time!

Comment: I have to connect with an app that it is using spring 2.5. In the future we want up version to all app, but now for I can connect with this app I need to use this version. We usually use new version.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean by "connect" but it sounds like you have a reason. It's easy to pickup older versions by following online tutorials.

Comment: In a future we are going to up version for that app, but I have to use this version now. I saw a lot of tutorials but it doesn´t work me and I don´t know why!! I had created a filter to intercept the request for js files, but neither... I don´t know to make yet!! It´s frustrating as something so easy or trivial, It is giving me much problems.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you're mapping all requests "/" to the dispatcher servlet. There is no controller for handling your resource urls so you'll probably get an error from spring because it can't map the url to a controller.

If you were using spring 3 then you would add this line to your servlet context.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

This assumes that all of your resources are in a folder called "resources" which resides in the WebRoot folder, not WEB-INF! If you use maven then it would be /src/main/webapp/resources. Don't put resources in WEB-INF, this is a private folder that hides content from the client. You can only put JSP's in WEB-INF if you're displaying them via a controller, the controller can see into this folder but the client/browser cannot.

You have a problem though because you're on an old version of spring which doesn't support the resources tag. I think what you'll have to do is override the servlet mapping for your resources to the default servlet instead of the spring front controller.

Something like this.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This assumes the same folder structure as the other example. You can tweak the mappings for your own project structure but just remember it should be in the WebRoot and not WEB-INF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to make some similar. I have a servlet-mapping into web.xml with url-pattern *.js and the app can see those js files. But I cann´t use it. When I execute the app in browser and when I go to see view page source it´s white the js file

Comment: I notice you've also configured spring security to intercept all urls. Have you set an allow-all rule for your resources? It could be that the user is unauthorized to view your JS. Failing that I think you need to setup log4j to view the debug output for spring. You should then see an explanation in the console that will pinpoint the problem. In fact, do that anyway if you haven't already. Setting up proper logging usually pinpoints problems like this right away.

Comment: This is something that I don´t have thinking, but I have commented all spring-security and this continues same. I continue without to see those js files. Can it be why the filter isn´t good or I have to return those js file?

Comment: Follow these instructions to setup logging: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-log4j-integration-example/ Once you've done that the error should present itself in the console.

Comment: I had already configured the log, but it doesn´t pint me anything error.

Comment: It will do if you set the logging levels correctly. The logging in the spring framework is quite detailed. I see you've also posted up some filter code too. Not sure where this comes into it. In your JSP the url to the JS is a relative URL. Can you see the JS file if you type the full path manually in the address bar?

Comment: First of all I want to thank your help to you. When the browser I put the path http://localhost:8090/Web_logistic/static/js/md5.js (now is localhost :)) and browser´s scream is in white, without js file.
This a part of my log4j
**log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=..\..\..\log\log.out
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n**

Answer (score 0):

Static files (css, js,..) can't stay inside the WEB-INF folder. They should be publicily available for the browser to read. Take them out

Comment: They can stay there if OP uses a resource handler.

Comment: It is not common then

Comment: Before I had this files into resource folder but neither it work me

Comment: You shouldn't put them into resource, instead in the webapp folder (default name). Are you using tomcat?
Try to create a folder called src/webapps. Put them there

Comment: Now I put it into src folder, Like this:
src
---static
-------js
In jsp file I put this: <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/static/js/md5.js" /> "></script>
And neither

Comment: Thanks for your response
I have created a filter and although already it don´t give me a mistake (I have status 200 with firebug) but I cann´t get anything of my javascript file yet.
I have put those files in the code of above

Comment: How is your folder structure now? have you put the md5.js file here: src/webapps/staticjs/md5.js ?

Comment: I have compiled my app for I show this js file and I have showed that this js files were empty. I think that I don´t server it good, 
therefore I can´t access to functions of my js files

Comment: My structure is src/main/static/js/md5.js

Comment: try with src/webapps/staticjs/md5.js.
webapps is the (default tomcat) pathname of a directory that may contain web applications

Comment: First of all I want to thank your help to you. Also I had that and neither. I use glassfish as server

Comment: No worries :) does it work? I'm afraid i can't help you with glassfish

Comment: this continues without work. About the new filter that I have made, can it be that it doesn´t serve my js files?